# Is there a Z3-announce mailing list?

Tags: z3

I just noted Z3 4.4.1 was released.

I couldn't find a Z3-announce mailing list. Does any one know if such mailing list exists?

**Edit:**
I realised I asked the same question in Z3 bug tracker. See the answer [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/71).

Comment: Yes, there is no dedicated list for that purpose as stated there. Also, the 4.4.1 release is literally a few minutes old, I haven't even had time to upload everything yet :)